# groupBy not in lodash source from npm

Tags: lodash

I have just installed lodash via npm:

npm install --save lodash

`groupBy` is not in the source, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're seeing, but, no it's definitely there.  [Here it is from github:](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L8086-L8092)

```
var groupBy = createAggregator(function(result, value, key) {
  if (hasOwnProperty.call(result, key)) {
    result[key].push(value);
  } else {
    result[key] = [value];
  }
});
```

Comment: It is in github but not when you do an npm install --save lodash

Comment: No; I checked that too, it's definitely there.